# What are the applications of the second part of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, weierstrass-approximation

> (Stone-Weierstrass) Let $K$ be compact HAusdorff and $A\subset C_\mathbb{R}(K)$ a (sub)algebra which sepearates points. Then either $\overline{A}=C_\mathbb{R}(K)$ or $\exists x_0$ such that $\overline{A}=\{ f\in C_\mathbb{R}(K): f(x_0)=0\}$

I have seen lots of applications of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to prove that a set is dense in $C(\mathbb{R})$. This is one possible conclusion of the theorem. The other is that if the algebra $A$ satisfies the hypothesis, then $\overline{A}=\{\text{all continuous functions which vanish at some } x_0\}$

What applications use this second result of the theorem, or is it just the degenerate case?

Comment: Even more versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem). People just use what's convenient. It's not that one version is more useful then another.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have clarified the question by stating the version I am using

Comment: With the stated verion you don't find dense subsets of $C(\Bbb R)$ as the reals are not compact?

Comment: @user The second part of the theorem isn't really a "result"; as you said, it's essentially the degenerate case.

Comment: @user Note that an equivalent (and more common, in my experience) framing of the result is as follows: *Let $K$ be compact Hausdorff and $A\subset C_\mathbb{R}(K)$ a subalgebra which sepearates points. Then $\overline{A}=C_\mathbb{R}(K)$ if and only if $A$ vanishies nowhere (i.e. $\nexists x_0 \in X$ such that $\overline{A}=\{ f\in C_\mathbb{R}(K): f(x_0)=0\}$)*

Comment: @user There is also the following technically stronger version of the result: *Let $K$ be compact Hausdorff and $A \subset C_{\Bbb R}(K)$ a subalgebra. Then $\bar A = C_{\Bbb R}(K)$ if and only if $A$ separates points and vanishes nowhere.*

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Correct, the reals are not compact

Comment: @BenGrossmann It sounds reasonable to me that there may be a nice application out there, framing the result to sound negative doesn't suggest there wont be.